# Couldn't connect to Amazon Workspaces from specific device, it works fine from other devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I couldn't connect to Amazon Workspace from specific Windows 11 device. Getting the error message:

> (Disconnected: The network has been lost (UDP))

When I try it from some other devices, it works fine. Please help!

I tried resetting the network by the below commands and restart the device, but it doesn't help:

```
netstat int ip reset
netstat winsock reset
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. You might receive a better response at: https://repost.aws/